# Explain in small words why IQueryable<T> is needed

Tags: .net, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

There's [this ... MSDN page, IQueryable(Of T) Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx). Can you do a better job explaining why we need a marker interface which doesn't add any methods over IEnumerable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It extends `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable<T>`. It may not have methods of its own, but it aggregates these other three interfaces as one, so you don't have to deal with them separately.

Answer (score 12):

[`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) also extends [`IQueryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx). Basically it's an `IQueryable` which can be enumerated in a strongly-typed way. (Both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable<T>` already extend `IEnumerable`, so it's not adding anything on that front.)

Now, having a strongly-typed `IQueryable` allows LINQ to SQL (etc) to be strongly typed - otherwise you couldn't write `Where` clauses etc without casting. The actual LINQ methods involved are in the [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx) type, largely mirroring the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) methods but taking *expression trees* instead of delegates. (If you haven't used expression trees before, they're basically data structures *describing* the code - whereas a delegate is the code itself. So you can execute a delegate, but you can examine an expression tree to see what it would do.)

Comment: it's been 7 years but since the offer by the estimable author has been made I'll take it up: is a dummy proof explanation of expression trees possible? perhaps for the benefit of future readers more so than me, coz Google is beckoning :)

Comment: @BKSpurgeon: I'll add a little bit, but it's not really the point of the question, so I think you'd be best off with a tutorial to be honest.

Answer (score 5):

`IQueryable<T>` is needed because it defines a contract that is required for a LINQ provider.  Many of the extension methods available on `IQueryable<T>` are designed to accept expressions rather than delegates.

This is important as a LINQ provider will need to analyze the expression tree rather than invoke a delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Use IQueryable if you want to translate a linq query to an expression tree (System.Linq).
From an expression tree you can easily translate your LINQ query to another language (SQL for Linq To SQL.
Another classic example is Linq to Google where you want this query :

```
var searchResult = from result 
                   in Google.Repository 
                   where result.Equals("i love linq") 
                   select result;
```

To translate to this url :

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=i+love+linq&aq=f&oq=&aqi=g10

Then you parse the page to get the results.